# wrapping a matched regular expression of html page while preserving the original html structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

it is hard to explain what I need in simple words, so I will put an example

say I need to match my inner html with the string "be"

original innerHTML is : `b</br>e`
expected new innerHTML is: `<span>b</br>e</span>`
actual new innerHTML is: `<span>be</span>`

what I do is I remove any html tag from my innerhtml so that my original html will be be, then I replace it with `<span>be</span>`,

now I am facing alot of problem preserving back the original html structure so that the results become `<span>b</br>e</span>`

thanks in advance

Comment: Check `childNodes` property of DOM element. Iterating over this nodes you can find only child text nodes without html tags

Comment: also check just `innerText` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this answer is based on the assumption that the "words" you're looking for are not huge parts of HTML, otherwise it becomes unrealistic.*

You might use a regex to find the searched "word", so avoiding to suppress tags.

Since it seems that HTML tags may occur anywhere, the trick is to accept a tag between each character of the "word".

That's said, here is how it might work:

```js
function span_word(word, html) {
    
    // prepare regex (accept a HTML tag between each character of $word)
    var regex = word[0];
    for (var i = 1, n = word.length; i < n; i++) {
        regex += '((?:<[^>]+>(?:[^<]*<\\/[^>]+>)?)?)*' + word[i];
    }
    
    // wrap any matching part in <span>
    var matchId = 0;
    return html.replace(
      new RegExp(regex, 'g'),
      function(match) {
        return '<span id="match' + ++matchId + '">' + match + '</span>';
      }
    );
}

document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('some-html-part');
  elem.innerHTML = span_word('lookfor', elem.innerHTML);
});
</script>
```

```css
span {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Go</button>
<div id="some-html-part">
  <p>Lorem ipsum lookfor lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum look<br />for lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

---

EDIT

The above snippet has been improved to take in account the OP's comments:

- the regex became `'((?:<[^>]+>(?:[^<]*<\\/[^>]+>)?)*)'`: this way it allows several tags (rather than only one) to appear between each character
- each generated `<span>` has an `id="match#"`, where `#` is the encountered match index from 1 to N

Comment: I think you meant to put a bunch of pluses instead of periods for concatenation. (You can ditch those dollar signs, too!)

Comment: I really like your idea, but for some reason, i can't get it to work, if you can provide a fiddle example, that would be awesome , and of course thanks for your efforts after all

Comment: @BelalMostafaAmin Turned my answer to working snippet.

Comment: DUDE: you are a PRINCE , can't thank you enough. Wish to you all the best, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: to make your regex more general and match nested or more than one html tag between the input string you can make the regular expression to be as following '((?:<[^>]+>(?:[^<]*<\\/[^>]+>)?)+)?'

Comment: @cFreed one last thing , what if I need to give each span an id="the current match #" like if this is the first one to match the id will be 1, if it is the second then the id is 2, I know how to do it explicity but not inline with replace, if you know please tell me

Comment: @BelalMostafaAmin 1) You're right: we can extend the regex capability to accept several tags; but rather than `((...)+)?` we can more simply use `((...)*)`; 2) see my updated answer.

Comment: dude , you are a pro